# Запятая или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

> Дайте сметану, что пожирнее.

Насколько я понял, знаки-то расставлены верно? Союзное слово "что" служит для связи придаточной определительной  с главной в сложноподчиненном предложении. Кроме того, союз "что" легко можно заменить на "которую". Только первый вариант более разговорный :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Розенталь в подобных конструкциях разговорного стиля рекомендует ставить запятую. Сравните: *Дайте сметану, которая пожирнее.*

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, знаки расставлены верно.